# Why is the variable name replaced by its value causing " 'xxx' should be declared" error?

Tags: variables, plsql, compiler-errors, sqlplus, identifier

I wrote the following PL/SQL block:

```
declare 
    v_name varchar2(20);
    v_sal integer;
begin
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('CREATE TABLE EMP5 (name varchar2(20),sal integer,primary key(name))');
    dbms_output.put_line('Enter name : ');
    v_name:=&v_name;
    dbms_output.put_line('salary : ');
    v_sal :=&v_sal;
    insert into emp5 (name,sal) values (v_name,v_sal);
end;
/
```

And then I got the following compiler output:

```
Enter a valeur for v_name : dhia
old 6 : v_name:=&v_name;
new 6 : v_name:=dhia;
Enter a valeur for v_sal : 10
old 8 : v_sal :=v_&sal;
new 8 : v_sal :=10;
v_name:=dhia;
      *
ERREUR at line 6 :
ORA-06550: line 6, colon 7 :
PLS-00201: the identifier 'DHIA' should be declared
ORA-06550: line 6, colon 1 :
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line9, colon 13 :
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 9, colon 1 :
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

My question is why the variable 'name' replaced by its value 'dhia' in the script causing that error, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use your variables this way, the expected behavior is to replace them by its values, your variables should not be the same as your columns names, please try the following:

```
declare 
varName varchar2(20);
varSal integer;
sql_stmt varchar2(200);
begin
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('CREATE TABLE EMP5 (name varchar2(20),sal integer,primary key(name))');
dbms_output.put_line('Enter name : ');
varName :=&varName;
dbms_output.put_line('salary : ');
varSal :=&varSal;
sql_stmt := 'INSERT INTO EMP5 VALUES (:1, :2)';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt USING varName, varSal; 
end;
/
```

Comment: No actually , this gives the exact same error msg , that's what i thought at first also , but it looks like the variable name have nothing to do with the issue , anyhow ill change it in the question

Comment: @DhiaHassen have you tried EXECUTE COMMAND with the insert query as what in the answer above?

Comment: Yes i copied and pasted your code above and i got the same error msg

Comment: You may have to enter the value of the variable v_name between single qoutations as 'Dhia'

Answer (score 0):

This is not compiler output, it's SQL*Plus output:

```
Enter a valeur for v_name : dhia
old 6 : v_name:=&v_name;
new 6 : v_name:=dhia;
```

`&v_name` is a [substitution variable](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_five.htm#SQPUG434) (also known as a define variable), which means SQL*Plus blindly replaces `&v_name` with the literal text `dhia` before sending it to the database for compilation and execution. The `new 6` line above is showing you what your code looks like after this text substitution. As you can see, `v_name := dhia;` would only be valid if there was another variable or function in scope named `dhia`. If you want to use a substitution variable for a text value, you need to quote it:

```
v_name := '&v_name';
```

This also means your `dbms_output` commands will not be executed until after the substitution, which makes them somewhat useless. If you want to capture input from the user, use the [`accept`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_five.htm#SQPUG446) command before the start of the PL/SQL block.

Another problem in your example is that if the `EMP5` table does not exist, the block won't compile because of the reference to a non-existent table in the `insert` command; but if it does exist then your `execute immediate` will fail. You need to either create the table in a separate step, or else use `execute immediate` for all references to it and handle the case where it already exists.